# OpenCV - canny edge detection not working properly

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I am new to OpenCV with Android. I am currently working on document detection demo app. What I did so far is as below:

**Original image** -> **Gray scale image** -> **GaussianBlur** -> **Canny edge detection** -> **finding contours** -> **draw Contours**

I am able to detect paper sheet perfectly as you can see in below image .

[image]

But it does not detect some documents. Below is one of them

[image]

I researched a lot about that and found that the problem lies in canny edge detection and below is the canny image :

[image]

As you can see , the edge detection is not perfectly linked and it does not connect edges at some point. That is the reason for that .

I have gone through the similar issue at : [How to select the best set of parameters in Canny Edge detection algorithm implemented in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324950/how-to-select-the-best-set-of-parameters-in-canny-edge-detection-algorithm-imple)
I have followed the solution but it didn't worked for me.

My canny detection code is as follow :

```
double otsu_thresold = Imgproc.threshold(mGray,edged,0,255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
Imgproc.Canny(mRgba, edged, otsu_thresold*0.5,otsu_thresold);
```

I don't know where I am wrong! What should I do to perfectly detect the document?

Comment: in order to enhance the edges use **morphological dilation**. See [THIS PAGE](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#morphological-ops).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have decided to stop making such edits since it overwhelms the active page with old content. Received as per another SO user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656890/measure-velocity-of-objects-in-a-video?noredirect=1#comment130031580_44656890

Answer (score 10):

First the method of performing **Canny edge detection** has to change. You are setting a lower and higher threshold in `cv2.Canny()`**manually**. You can do this automatically. I used [THIS LINK](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/04/06/zero-parameter-automatic-canny-edge-detection-with-python-and-opencv/) as reference.

Use the following snippet:

```
v = np.median(gray_image)

#---- apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median----
lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
edged = cv2.Canny(gray_image, lower, upper)
cv2.imshow('Edges',edged)
```

***So what am I doing here?***

I am taking the **median** value of the gray scale image. The `sigma` value of 0.33 is chosen to set the `lower` and `upper` threshold. **`0.33`** value is generally used by statisticians for data science. So it is considered here as well.

This is what I got:

[image]

To enhance this edge information I performed **morphological dilation** using the `cv2.MORPH_CROSS` kernel:

[image]

Now just perform the usual `cv2.findContours()` operation and draw the *biggest* contour.

:)

Comment: I was using otsu's method to find threshold values dynamically . I also applied your solutions but it didn't worked and also slower down camera frames.

Comment: you mean finding the edges is slow?

Comment: No , I mean camera preview frame becomes slow because of threshold computations

Comment: That might happen because it is calculating the median of the image and setting threshold based on that value

Comment: Yes, it degrades performance of camera preview . By the way , thanks for your efforts . Do you have any other solution ?

Comment: Your question asked for a better edge detection mechanism that is why I answered it. I have no idea how it degrades performance

Comment: how do i save largest contour's path ? i want to draw the contour with svg path

Answer (score 3):

I've got better results with a small adaption of the algorithm posted by Jeru Luke.

On document detection, we rather search for the dark shadowy edges of a document:

- For light images, like with white paper, median is high and "255 - median" performs better than just median
- For small values sigma is too small to produce a wide enought range.

Here is my C#-algorithm:

```
    double s = 0.33;
    if (imageMedian > 191) // light images
    {
      cannyTh1 = (int)Math.Max(0, (1 - 2*s) * (255 - imageMedian));
      cannyTh2 = (int)Math.Max(85, (1 + 2*s) * (255 - imageMedian));
    }
    else if (imageMedian > 127)
    {
      cannyTh1 = (int)Math.Max(0, (1 - s) * (255 - imageMedian));
      cannyTh2 = (int)Math.Min(255, (1 + s) * (255 - imageMedian));
    }
    else if (imageMedian < 63) // dark images
    {
      cannyTh1 = (int)Math.Max(0, (1 - 2*s) * imageMedian);
      cannyTh2 = (int)Math.Max(85, (1 + 2*s) * imageMedian);
    }
    else
    {
      cannyTh1 = (int)Math.Max(0, (1 - s) * imageMedian);
      cannyTh2 = (int)Math.Min(255, (1 + s) * imageMedian);
    }
```

Additionally, the result can be improved for some documents by

- sharpening the image after using the median filter
- using stronger median filter
- computing median and perform canny filter for seperate parts of the image, because shadow and light influence can differ largely on parts of the image

Comment: thanks for your efforts but i am not working on this project anymore , will check your solution and get back to you later.